# A quick rebus puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, rebus

**This riddle depends on the colour of the pictures. So it is not friendly for colourblind people. All inconveniences are regretted**

A simple one this time. No hidden meaning or clues. Let's see how fast this one gets solved. :)

> Do note that the path shown in the second picture has no significance whatsoever to the puzzle.

[image]

Hint below

> As I have said before, the path is not important here. But do take a closer look at the trees. Colourblind people may not be able to differentiate though and I apologize in advance for that

Comment: Hopefully the tags should help.

Comment: @downvoter, if you cannot understand the puzzle then there is no reason to downvote it :). I even gave the appropriate tags.

Comment: Ah. "colourblind people may not be able to differentiate". This means I quit.

Comment: @Marius Sorry! Next time I will make a puzzle that does not depend on the colours in the picture to solve it!!

Comment: @Marius It is unfortunate that you are colourblind (if that is what you are imposing), but bear in mind, this is not the OP's fault. In my humble opinion, I don't think this puzzle deserves a downvote; although the puzzle might look ridiculous to those that are colourblind, I am certain this was not deliberately intended by the OP, and thus he/she is not culpable. Of course the OP is partly to blame, to say the least, as he/she created the actual puzzle, but then again...

Comment: @user477343 I should have made it known in the post. I will do so now!

Comment: @user477343. If you are implying that I downvoted this, I assure you I didn't. I don't up/downvote what I don't understand. And I didn't blame the OP.

Comment: @Marius oh, ok. Well, nevermind then, and apologies for the false accusations :P

Comment: Haha guys relax. Thanks for the upvote again. @user477343 would you like to try?

Comment: ....I am not great at rebus puzzles. I don't even know where to start! But yeah, I'll have a go. Why not? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess, but is it

> The grass is greener on the other side

Because

> The two pictures have bamboo (a grass) and the right photo is greener than the left.

Comment: @R.D actually, this is probably the answer anyways. (Murphy's Law) :P

Comment: And we have a winner!

Comment: So many hints thrown out here XD But good job.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the hint, maybe...

> Grass is greener on the other side?

since

> bamboo is a type of grass, right?

Comment: Ooohhh, @sedrick beat you by $53$ seconds... now his *answer* is greener than the other side...

Comment: Argh, too slow yet again!!

Comment: Haha, But there you go. You deserve the upvote

Comment: I was half-expecting there to be a hidden sled (or maybe led) somewhere in the second picture. Then the answer would have been that we were "bamboozled" by R.D :)

Comment: I wish there was a smaller tick that would award, say, $15$ rep for those who have the answer but did not get accepted from being just that bit too slow... and @R.D, I might make a rebus myself, actually. I'll see if I can make one, even though I'm not good at them :P

Comment: That pun. I think jafe should be able to crack my next puzzle. Too bad I'm not that good in wordplay.

Comment: @user477343 looking forward to it

Comment: @R.D Alright I made it :D

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be

> Clear the way?

Comment: Nope. Not even close. But I appreciate the effort.